# FileNotFoundError : while running unittest python

Tags: python, python-unittest

For my new Python project, I followed the following directory structure as suggested by, http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/

```
Project
      solution
          __init__.py
          trial.txt
          trial.py
      tests
          __init__.py
          test.py
```

Where `trial.py's demo` reads `trial.text` and perform some operation

```
with open("trial.txt") as f:
    f.readlines()
```

The code works and tests works fine when I run it from `project` directory

The `test` throws file not found error on `trial.txt` when running from inside of `tests` directory

I have also added a context module for `tests`

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../solution')))

import trial
```

Comment: Try specifying package?

Comment: refer here https://pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/

Comment: @AkshayKathpal But I want the test and main code to be in separate folders

Comment: Try this instead in your tests `import ..solution.trial` You need to add an empty `__init__.py` file in solution folder also.

Comment: @RajanChahan Then I am getting `Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: I have write the code @BhavaniRavi

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by adding this before opening the file

```
file_path = (os.path.dirname(__file__))+"/trail.txt"
with open(filepath,"r") as f:
    f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to make it write

Make a python script in the **Solution** directory and name it as

```
name -> __init__.py

import trial
```

and save this file in the **Solution** directory

Now try to **import Solution** from **test.py**
like this one right here:

```
from Solution import trial
trial.main()
```

But make sure the code in the **trial.py** file in some function like **main()** and then you can call like

```
trial.main()
```

For better understanding see this example of my directory

[image]

[image]

```
The file data.py and __init__.py are in the same directory. You can see here and try to solve.
```

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trial.txt'`
Still the error remains while reading the file not while importing

Comment: i have tested it on my system

Comment: I run `test.py` from inside of `tests` folder and when i print `os.getcwd()` I get this `/home/Bhavani/skcript/tests`

Comment: ya os.getcwd() will show your current working directory where your script is present. I understood your problem. you want to access the file within solution folder I have posted the images